# when double-clicking one element, another gets selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selection

I've written an image scroller in html/css/js, a very simple one: right button is clicked, I go through all images inside "holder"-div and change the class of the image after the one with classname="current".

But that's not where the problem lies, I think. Whenever I successively click on the left or the right button, the image in the div gets selected (blue selection box). If I successively click the left button, even the text above it gets selected.

```
<div class="grid_4 omega image_box">
    <div id="txt_choose" class="image_txt">
        this is helpful text
    </div>
    <div id="alt_spacer"></div>
    <div id="image_content" class="image_content" onclick="chooseImageType(this)">
        <div id="current" class="current"><img src="images/default1.png" /></div>
        <div id="current" class="hidden"><img src="images/default2.png" /></div>
    </div>
    <!--- left button --->
    <div class="image_btn_left" onclick="showPrev()"></div>

    <!--- right button --->
    <div class="image_btn_right" onclick="showNext()"></div>
</div>
```

and this is the css:

```
.image_btn_right
{
    width           : 20px;
    height          : 20px;
    position        : relative;
    float           : left;
    margin-top      : -170px;
    margin-left     : 260px;
    z-index         : 4;
    cursor          : pointer;
    background-image: url('../images/right.png');
}
.image_btn_left
{
    width           : 20px;
    height          : 20px;
    position        : relative;
    float           : left;
    margin-top      : -170px;
    margin-left     : 20px;
    z-index         : 4;
    cursor          : pointer;
    background-image: url('../images/left.png');
}
.image_content
{
    height          : 280px;
    background-color: white;
    margin          : 10px;
}
```

on request, my javascript:

```
function showNext()
{
//vars
var shown = false;
var current;

$('#image_content > div').each(function()
{
    if($(this).attr('class') == "current")
    {
        current = $(this);
        shown   = true;
    }
    else if($(this).attr('class') == "hidden" && shown == true)
    {
        current.hide();
        current.attr('class', 'prev');
        current.attr('id', '');
        $(this).show();
        $(this).attr('class', 'current');
        $(this).attr('id', 'current');
        shown = false;
    }
});
}
```

Is there anyway to stop the image and the text above to be selected like that (without actually making them not selectable)?
Could it be because of the relative position of the buttons and their z-index..?

Comment: Can you post your javascript as well?

Comment: I've added my javascript

Comment: could you something using jsfiddle.net to get an idea of your doing.

Comment: happy to: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9AWm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and it was painfully easy.. >_>

I just needed to wrap the buttons in another div, so they became more eperated from the rest of the html.

Like so:

```
<div>
    <!--- left button --->
    <div class="image_btn_left" onclick="showPrev()"></div>

    <!--- right button --->
    <div class="image_btn_right" onclick="showNext()"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in your JS fiddle.

```
function showNext()
{

    //vars
    var shown = false;
    var current;
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
   $('#image_content > div').each(function()
    {
        if($(this).attr('class') == "current")
        {
            current = $(this);
            shown   = true;
        }
        else if($(this).attr('class') == "hidden" && shown == true)
        {
            current.hide();
            current.attr('class', 'prev');
            current.attr('id', '');
            $(this).show();
            $(this).attr('class', 'current');
            $(this).attr('id', 'current');
            shown = false;
        }
    });
}

function showPrev()
{
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    //vars
    var prev_present = false;
    var prev;

    $('#image_content > div').each(function()
    {
        if($(this).attr('class') == "prev")
        {
            prev         = $(this);
            prev_present = true;
        }
        else if($(this).attr('class') == "current" && prev_present == true)
        {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).attr('class', 'hidden');
            $(this).attr('id', '');
            prev.show();
            prev.attr('class', 'current');
            prev.attr('id', 'current');
            prev_present = false;
        }
    });
}
```

best regards
Jonas

Comment: I added your code, but it's not what I wanted. It made me not able to select text, which is pretty annoying for visitors. And it did'nt solve my problem. Try it yourself if you'd like with the jsfiddle I posted in the comments of my original question post.

Comment: Try your fiddle now. Is that what your looking for?

Comment: I wasnt able to create a jsfiddle account when I made this, so i don't think I can see any changes made.. :s
What did you do exactly?

Comment: Paste my code without the $(document).mousemove(function() {  and }); inside your "click" handlers.

Comment: I see what your trying to do, tryig to disable the selection once you click the button. But it works just a bit too late, it still selects it half a second before unselecting it all.. : \

Comment: Edited my answer. How about now?